# Reference Request - Dirichlet's Proof of the Convergence of Fourier Sums

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, reference-request, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Where can I find Dirichlet's proof of the convergence of Fourier Sums? I am not looks for his paper, but a modern explanation in English.

Comment: I would imagine that [Katznelson](https://books.google.com/books/about/An_Introduction_to_Harmonic_Analysis.html?id=gkpUE_m5vvsC) gives a proof, though I don't have the book in front of me right now.

Comment: You can find a proof in Whittaker and Watson's old classic "A Course in Modern Analysis".

Answer (score 0):

One of the only modern approaches to the subject of pointwise convergence that I have ever found is

   https://www.jstor.org/stable/2321220?origin=JSTOR-pdf&seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

It does not seem that many people are aware of this paper.